# How to compile and install drivers in linux from source code

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, drivers

I am using the repository [linux repository torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/) for installing usbip (and it's drivers). I have done two steps in the install section of [readme](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/usb/usbip/README). The last thing left is the "Compile & install USB/IP drivers" step. The driver folder for usbip has the .c files, Makefile and Kconfig file in [driver folder](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/usbip).
There is no instructions in the readme as to how to do it.
How to compile and install using the source code for Debian Bullseye?
My Debian version is `11.2` and kernel version `5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64` (a non standard kernel)

Answer (score 3):

In Debian Bullseye, the USB/IP driver modules are already in the standard kernel package, and the `usbip-utils` have been packaged as `usbip`.

**So, you don't need to compile anything.**

You can verify that the driver modules are available using this command:

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip
```

It should list four files:

```
usbip-core.ko  usbip-host.ko  usbip-vudc.ko  vhci-hcd.ko
```

To install the user-space tools (the `usbip` command and the `usbipd` daemon):

```
sudo apt install usbip
```

Comment: no luck. it says "no such file or directory", the usb folder just has one host folder. Will copying these files work?

Comment: [The standard kernel package for Debian Bullseye definitely has those modules.](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64/filelist) Just what kernel version are you running? Please edit your question to add the outputs of `cat /etc/debian_version` and `uname -r`.

Comment: ```11.2``` and ```5.10.0-11-cloud-amd64```

Comment: You have a kernel that's been customized for cloud provider use, and one of the customizations is that the `usbip` functionality has been disabled. It's possible you cannot change the running kernel using the "usual" procedure, but you may have to use the cloud provider's management web UI for it, and the available options may be limited.